# Is it possible to have a 1 GB and 2 GB Ram installed in a One Desktop Computer?

Tags: windows, desktop-computer

Is it possible to have a 1 GB and 2 GB Ram installed in a One Desktop Computer?
I badly needed your opinion guys.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. A answer to your question highly depends on the motherboard used. Therefore without further information you will not get reliable answers.

Comment: And probably also the specs of the memory sticks you want to insert (the question sounds as if you have old memory lying around that you want to add).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but they won't beneficiate from "Dual Channel" technology which doubles the memory bandwidth if two identical sticks are used.

Just make sure the new RAM stick is compatible with your motherboard in terms of frequency.

Answer (score 0):

1 and 2 GB chips are possible to work together in 1 computer, if they are both compatibile with motherboard(see type, DDR, DDR2, DDR3). Also, keep in mind that they'll both work at the speed of the slower one.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can install multiple rams, but it depends on your mother board, most mother boards have atleast 2 slots

*make sure the ram you purchase is fit for your motherboard before plunging it in.